# Set state for element in array [react-native]

Tags: react-native

I have a view

```
renderFrame = () => {
   const frames = []
   for(let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
     frames.push (
       <TouchableOpacity style={this.state.isActive ? styles.frameItemActive : styles.frameItem} key={i} onPress={this.handleChoiceTime.bind(this, i)}>
         <Text style={{color: '#8E8E93', fontSize: 17}}>{i}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   }
   return frames   
}
```

how to set state for element in frame, default is false, when click then is true, double click then is false

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

I have kept the frames outside the render method and used flatlist. Now When the button is pressed the isFrameActive flag of that particular frame element will change and re-render. So this should work as per your requirement. Give a try!

```
this.state = {
  frames : [
   {
     id: 1,
     value: 1,
     isFrameActive: true
   }, 
   {
     id: 2,
     value: 2,
     isFrameActive: true
   }, 
   {
     id: 3,
     value: 3,
     isFrameActive: true
   }
 ]
};

handleChoiceTime = (index, item) => {
  this.state.frames[index].isActive = !this.state.frames[index].isActive;
  this.setState({
    frames: this.state.frames
  })
}

renderFrame = (item) => {
  <TouchableOpacity style={item.isFrameActive ? styles.frameItemActive : styles.frameItem} key={item.id} onPress={this.handleChoiceTime.bind(index, item)}>
    <Text style={{color: '#8E8E93', fontSize: 17}}>{item.value}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
}

render() {
  <Flatlist
    data={this.state.frames}
    renderItem = {(item) => this.renderFrame(index, item)}
    extraData={this.state}
  />
};
```